# Threading 2 functions and continue the rest of codes after the 2 functions are over

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to run 2 functions at the same time. Then wait until those 2 functions are over, and it can start processing the rest of codes.  I tried to use `thread` module but it just continue running without waiting those 2 functions finished.  My example codes are as below:

```
import os, sys
import threading
from threading import Thread

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.method_1()

    def method_1(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print ('new')

            def run(self):
                threading.Thread(target = function_a, args=(self,)).start()
                threading.Thread(target = function_b, args=(self,)).start()

            def function_a(self):
                for i in range(10):
                    print (1)

            def function_b(self):
                for i in range(10):
                    print (2)

            run(self)


Example()
```

If the above codes get executed, the `print ("new")` inside `method_1` will just print out immediately even before the `function_a` and `function_b` are over in each round of the `for i in range(3)`. However, what I want is that the `new` will only be printed out as `function_a` and `function_b` are finished printing `1` and `2`.

That is, the codes should stop at `threading` and wait for the `function_a` and `function_b` to finish so that it can continue processing the next `i` in the `for i in range(3)`.

If anyone know how to solve this, please let me know. Appreciated!!

Comment: I am no expert in threading, why not use multiprocessing module if you want to run two functions in parallel. That'd be a more solid approach

Comment: I am no expert in `threading` nor `multiprocessing` too... Could you pls provide an example or solution using `multiprocessing` if possible? Appreciated!!

Comment: See if this will help  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aysceqdGFw8&t=482s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python?rq=1

Comment: I don't know if your videos is suitable for this questions.. Because for my question there is a `for loop` before the `threading`. But there's no `for loop` in that video.  I just want the `threading` stops before the functions are finished so it can start processing the next round of the `for loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `join` the threads (join means "wait for it to finish"). See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join). Depending on your problem, you may want to use `multiprocessing` instead, as mentioned in the comments. I'll proceed under the assumption that you do want to do threading.

Defining a class with methods to ask your question was unnecessary (and, even worse, you're redefining  `run`, `function_a`, and `function_b` on every iteration). Just use some functions. You can turn them into methods later if you need to.

```
import time
import threading

def function_a():
    for i in range(5):
        print('a', i)
        time.sleep(.1)

def function_b():
    for i in range(5):
        print('b', i)
        time.sleep(.1)

def run():
    thread_a = threading.Thread(target = function_a)
    thread_b = threading.Thread(target = function_b)

    thread_a.start()
    thread_b.start()

    print('threads started')

    return thread_a, thread_b

for i in range(3):
    print('new', i)

    thread_a, thread_b = run()

    print('about to join threads')

    thread_a.join()
    thread_b.join()

    print('threads joined')
```

The `sleep`s are just there to show that the two threads really are running at the same time. Example output (which may vary from run to run depending on exact timing):

```
new 0
a 0
b 0
threads started
about to join threads
a 1
b 1
a 2
b 2
a 3
b 3
a 4
b 4
threads joined
new 1
a 0
b 0
threads started
about to join threads
a 1
b 1
a 2
b 2
a 3
b 3
a 4
b 4
threads joined
new 2
a 0
b 0
threads started
about to join threads
a 1
b 1
b 2
a 2
b 3
a 3
b 4
a 4
threads joined
```

EDIT: class-based example

```
class Example():
    def function_a(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print('a', i)
            time.sleep(.1)

    def function_b(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print('b', i)
            time.sleep(.1)

    def get_threads(self):
        thread_a = threading.Thread(target = self.function_a)
        thread_b = threading.Thread(target = self.function_b)

        thread_a.start()
        thread_b.start()

        print('threads started')

        return thread_a, thread_b

    def run(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print('new', i)

            thread_a, thread_b = self.get_threads()

            print('about to join threads')

            thread_a.join()
            thread_b.join()

            print('threads joined')

e = Example()
e.run()
```

Comment: Umm actually all these class/method/function has to remain the exact same structures... Because I'm building a much larger program and it's just a very small part of codes in this example.

Comment: No worries - it should be easy to adapt my example to make the structure more like yours. Just move the functions you define in the loop into the class definition, and `join` the threads before you go to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Could you pls provide an solution with a class like mine? I tried but it didn't work... It's just very confusing with those `self` arguments involved.

Comment: @ryan9025 Done.

Comment: Umm...thanks but I need the `run`, `funciton_a` and `function_b` inside the `method_1`. I'm still trying to revise your codes but could you pls provide an solution just in the exact same structure of my codes? Cos I put this example in this structure for a reason... Really appreciated!!

Comment: @ryan9025 You really don't. I'm having trouble imagining a situation where you couldn't define them on the class itself and just pass in whatever information they need from inside `run`. You almost certainly don't need to redefine them on every loop like you do in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157072/discussion-between-josh-karpel-and-ryan9025).

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the other answer, you need to join the threads. This example keeps your structure. I have added a sleep there so that you can see it works (otherwise buffered output might mess things up).

```
import os, sys
import threading
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.method_1()

    def method_1(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print ('new')

            def run(self):
                a=threading.Thread(target = function_a, args=(self,))
                b=threading.Thread(target = function_b, args=(self,))
                a.start()
                b.start()
                a.join()
                b.join()

            def function_a(self):
                for i in range(10):
                    print (1)

            def function_b(self):
                for i in range(10):
                    print (2)

            run(self)
            sleep(1)


Example()
```

Comment: Appreciated!! Sorry that I have to give the answer to the other one becos he answers first.  But this solution is perfect as well